# Remove Multiple Players from Ubuntu Sound Menu is not working on 14.04

Tags: sound, 14.04, uninstall, menu

The fallowing procedure is not working:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-remove-multiple-players-from-ubuntu-sound-menu

I have tried to put vlc there with no success.

Any help?

Comment: your question is not clear. do want to remove it or put it there?

Answer (score 0):

The new [instructions on OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/remove-players-ubuntu-sound-menu) worked for me, here is a summary:
**dconf-editor**: com > canonical > indicator > sound
Double click on the closed brackets next to **interested-media-players** and delete the players you wish to remove from the Sound Menu, but leave in the square brackets and don’t delete any commas or apostrophes from items you wish to keep.
To avoid having to repeat the process add them to the **blacklisted-media-player** section.
Remember to enclose each player in **apostrophes** with a comma separating multiple entries. They must also be inside the square brackets — so double check before exiting.